# How to get TextBlock's Text value out of a StackPanel inside a Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I want to know how to get the text value out of a TextBlock that's inside a StackPanel that's inside a button in WPF, it goes pretty much like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image.png"));

    StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel();
    stackPnl.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    stackPnl.Margin = new Thickness(10);
    stackPnl.Children.Add(img);

    TextBlock txtBlck = new TextBlock();
    txtBlck.Text = "this is a test!";
    stackPnl.Children.Add(txtBlck);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Content = stackPnl;
    btn.Click += test_click;
    myPanel.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

And test_click:

```
private void test_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Text = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
}
```

Now of course what I get after I click on the button is this `System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel`, which I guess it's pretty obvious since the StackPanel is the actual content of the button, but like I said, I need to know how to get only the Text value of the TextBlock, so in that case txtBox should display `this is a test!`. How can this be done?, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself as well as I could have, I don't need just to get the text out of a random TextBlock, I know that's easy, I need the text inside the TextBlock inside the StackPanel of the button, the idea is for several buttons to get created programmatically, including their contents, so when I call the click events I get whatever was asigned to that specific button.

Comment: And the buttons are created with the StackPanel inside so they can have images, so it kinda looks like an icon but with all the events of a regular button.

Answer (score 0):

From top of my head:
1. Store instance of TextBlock locally and use it when needed
2. Create DependencyProperty and bind it to TextBlock. It that case you will always have latest value in this DP.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will be

```
TextBlock txtBlck = new TextBlock();
txtBlck.Name = "SomeName";
txtBlck.Text = "this is a test!";
```

and than

```
private void test_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Text = SomeName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button Content is your stackpanel not your textblock, then to have the textblock content you need to replace:

txtBox.Text = (sender as Button).Content;

by this

```
txtBox.Text = txtBlck.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

if u seriusly want text from textblock then y dont u make textblock public and use it.

```
public TextBlock txtBlck = new TextBlock();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel();
            stackPnl.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            stackPnl.Margin = new Thickness(10);


            txtBlck.Text = "this is a test!";
            stackPnl.Children.Add(txtBlck);

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = stackPnl;
            btn.Click +=btn_Click;
            myPanel.Children.Add(btn);
        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtBox.Text = txtBlck.Text;
        }
```

Comment: yes this will work. if you just move it out of main method to main class

Comment: doesnt matter how many controls you have this will keep the last value until program is closed, or if you dont want to do this way then better use properties to achieve this.